# Open another modal box on closing first

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have a modal box that has a text on it and a link with a onClick event that opens a new modal.

This link, outside the modal runs correctly but inside doesn't makes anything. I gived it the class 'simplemodal-close' (same as the close image) to force it close this box and open other

```
<a href='javascript:$.modal($(\'#formNuevo\'))' class='simplemodal-close' >Editar</a>
```

This is the code, the outside box link is the same without the class.

The functionality i need is when I click the close image, close normally, and when i click the link close the current box and open another with the ID shown in the href.

From now, thanks everyone
Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one modal open at a time. Here's an example of how to close one and open another:

http://jsbin.com/aqavo3/edit